# Limit relating to curvature

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I recently learned about curvature in my Calc III class and have been trying to derive the formulas for it based off of this definition: curvature = reciprocal of radius of oscillating circle at a point on a curve. So taking $r(t)$ as a vector valued function and $T(t)$ as the unit tangent, I have that $\cos(\Delta \theta)=T(t)\cdot T(t+\Delta t)$, then for when $t=x$,
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\lim_{h\to0}-\frac{T(x)\cdot T'(x+h)}{\sqrt{1-(T(x)\cdot T(x+h))^2}}.$$
From the fact that $R\,d\theta =ds$ where $R$ is the radius of curvature and $s$ is arc length, the limit above should be equal to $\frac{ds/dt}{R}=\frac{\lvert r'(t) \rvert}{R}$. I know there are many formulas for the curvature/radius of curvature, but how does one evaluate the limit above to derive any of those?

Comment: What is $\theta$? Is this a curve in the plane or in 3-space?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, I was assuming the notation was known. It’s the angle between the two vectors in the tangent plane, the vectors are tangent to a parametric curve. I recently realized I’m dumb and that the bottom is just the cross product of the two vectors so and since T’ is orthogonal to T the limit comes to the magnitude of T’ * sin/sin so the result is just the magnitude of T’

Comment: I think I do know the correct answer. This is for plane curves and $\theta(t)$ is the angle that $T(t)$ makes with the positive $x$-axis. Then one way of defining curvature is in fact $\kappa = \dfrac{d\theta}{ds}$, which gives your equation $ds = \dfrac 1{\kappa}d\theta$.  I do not see where you are getting your other equation from.

Comment: @TedShifrin the equation rd(theta)=ds comes from pretty much the definition of the oscillating circle. If the circle very closely approximates the curve then a small shift in arc legnth in the curve will be approximately equal to a small shift in the arc legnth of the circle, which is exactly its radius*change in theta

Comment: Provided you explain why *that* change in $\theta$ is the change in the $\theta$ as I defined it. I don't understand your $d\theta/dt$ equation. It seems to be nonsense.

Comment: @TedShifrin it’s simple geometry and calculus, draw a tangent line of a curve at a certain point and another one near that point and draw perpendicular lines from those lines originating at the point of tangency, the point at which the perpendicular lines intersect is the center of a circle that’s about the same as the oscillating circle at that point, and taking the limit as the tangent line near the point approaches the point gives the oscillating circle. The angle between the two vectors is the same as the angle between the perpendicular lines.

Comment: OK, fine. (By the way, I have written a textbook on differential geometry, so I know a little bit about the subject.) Your $d\theta/dt$ equation remains nonsense to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought the concept was relatively simple, if you search up curvature on this site you’ll find some helpful posts that may allow you to understand the formula in my post.

Comment: I think I'm done with you. Good luck.

Comment: @TedShifrin I found the solution already, thank you though

Comment: (Added minor formatting changes) Does your original equation come from the derivative of the arccosine?

Comment: Also I don't think your explanation of what $\theta$ is (a few comments ago) is correct

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger yes, sorry for not clarifying that in my post

Comment: @uhhhhidk Can you clarify it, then? It's still not clear exactly how you derived it

Comment: If it's a geometric argument I would recommend drawing and uploading a picture

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I didn’t put in an explanation of what theta was because I searched the forum for an explanation before posting and saw many others using that notation so I thought it was something well known, my fault for assuming that. I’m fairly certain that what I have is correct though, I drew out what I did and my result matched the formula of the radius of curvature

Comment: Known notation or not, you still haven't convinced me that _you_ understand what $\theta$ is.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger the angle between two tangent lines on a curve. As the two tangent lines approach each other, the change in arc legnth with respect to theta gives the radius of the oscillating circle, because theta is also the angle formed by the perpendicular lines extending from the points of tangency on the tangent lines. If the two lines are close enough to a certain point, the surface area between them should be approximately the radius of curvature at that point times the angle between the two lines. My work shows change in theta with respect to the parameter of the function.

Comment: @uhhhhidk That's $d\theta$ you're describing, not $\theta$

Comment: $\theta(t)$ should be the angle between the tangent line at the point $r(t)$ and some reference line (usually taken to be the $x$-axis)

Comment: And you surely want "arclength", not "surface area", as there are no surfaces here!

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger yeah I meant arc length sorry. I’m kinda bad with notation but my work checks out and I got the correct result so I’m assuming my derivation was correct